# Placeholder text not showing (pyside/pyqt)

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

Learning PySide, I'm tweaking a text edit widget (QLineEdit) and trying to set the placeholder text using setPlaceHolderText as in the code snippet below (which I invoke from `main`). Unfortunately, it is not working as I expected. The code runs, but the text box is blank, does not show the placeholder text. I am in Windows 7, Python 2.7 (working in iPython).

```
class MyTextEdit(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.textEditor=QtGui.QLineEdit(self) 
        self.textEditor.move(50,15)
        self.textEditor.setPlaceholderText("Don't mind me.") 
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 50)
        self.show()
```

Anyone understand what I'm doing wrong? I'm following examples from the following sites:

http://nullege.com/codes/search/PyQt4.QtGui.QLineEdit.setPlaceholderText

http://www.pythoncentral.io/pyside-pyqt-tutorial-interactive-widgets-and-layout-containers/

And don't see what I'm doing differently.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As your widget only contains only one component (the `QLineEdit`), that component will always grab the focus initially. The placeholder text is [only shown](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) if the edit is empty and *does not* have the focus*.

A simple solution would be to focus a different component befor showing your widget, e.g.
by inserting `self.setFocus()` before `self.show()`.
The downside is that this way the user has to click into the text field or press <kbd>Tab</kbd> before being able to write into the field. To avoid that, you can intercept the `keyPress` event on the widget.

Example:

```
class MyTextEdit(QtGui.QWidget):
    '''Some positioning'''
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.textEditor=QtGui.QLineEdit(self) 
        self.textEditor.move(50,15)
        self.textEditor.setPlaceholderText("Hi I'm de fault.") 
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 200, 50)
        self.setFocus()
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, evt):
        self.textEditor.setFocus()
        self.textEditor.keyPressEvent(evt)
```

*Note: This has changed in [Qt5](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop) where the paceholder text is shown as long as the line edit is empty. Unfortunately PySide doesn't support Qt5 (yet), so you'd have to use PyQt5.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that lucid and helpful response.

Comment: How to set  particular color for the placeholder text

Comment: Hmmm, not so easy, would be nice if there was a stylesheet [sub-control](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-sub-controls) for this, but there isnt. Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/mia08m1H) should work, using an event filter to change the style sheet of the component as needed.